# Partial differential equations and semigroups: explanation of an example.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory, semigroup-of-operators

The semigroup theory (as presented in [Pazy's book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Semigroups_of_Linear_Operators_and_Appli.html?id=sIAyOgM4R3kC&redir_esc=y)) give us theorems that ensures existence of solutions for the abstract cauchy problem

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dt}u(t)=A[u(t)];&&t\in[0,\infty)\\
u(0)=f&&
\end{align*}\right.,\tag{1}$$
where
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(t)=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{u(t+h)-u(t)}{h}.$$

So, in some applications of semigroup theory to partial differential equations, we need to rewrite a given problem in the form $(1)$.

Here is an example that was taken of [Goldstein's book](http://books.google.com.br/books/about/Semigroups_of_linear_operators_and_appli.html?id=kybvAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y):

[image]

**Question:** since each limit is taken in a different sense, why can we formally identify $\partial w/\partial t$ with $du/dt$? Could someone explain me why does it make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: At this stage the identification is only formal. Observe, that he does not fix a Banach space. To me, this is an indication than he wants to show the general strategy without getting lost in technical details. To make this rigorous he must  later use semigroup theory to solve the abstract problem and reinterpret the solution for the original problem.

Comment: @UweStroinski If we want to solve the problem above (at least in some elementary sense), we need to find $w$ such that 
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left\|\frac{w(x,t+h)-w(x,t)}{h}-\Delta w(x,t)\right\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=0.$$
If I'm not wrong, when we use semigroup theory we get (at least in some cases) a $w$ that just satisfies
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left\|\frac{w(\cdot,t+h)-w(\cdot,t)}{h}-\Delta w(\cdot,t)\right\|_X=0,$$
where $X$ is a suitable functional space. Is it what you mean by "reinterpret the solution"?

Comment: Yes. The semigroup $T$ can be applied to all initial values $f$. As you correctly remark, the resulting function $T(\cdot)f$ is in general not differentiable. It can however be interpreted as a solution of some integrated version of your equation. If you do this then the existence of a $C_0$-semigroup is equivalent to existence, uniqueness and continuous dependence on the initial values.

Comment: It seems some books doesn't explain explicitly that a solution for a PDE obtained via semigroup theory in fact is not a solution in the "classical" sense (because it can be not differentiable in variable $t$ as you said). Do you know some book that explain it explicitly? (the authors I consulted include Pazy,Clément, Goldstein, Hille, Engel, Vrabie and Kantorivtz).

Comment: In the Nagel-Engel book it is Lemma 1.3 on p. 50. Equation (1.6) is the so called mild solution. This is further explained on pp. 145.

Comment: @UweStroinski When I said "is not a solution in the 'classical' sense" I meant that $w$ doesn't satisfies
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left\|\frac{w(x,t+h)-w(x,t)}{h}-\Delta w(x,t)\right\|_{\mathbb{R}^n}=0.$$
This isn't the meaning of "classical" in your reference in which "not differentiable in $t$" means that $w$ doesn't satisfies"
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\left\|\frac{w(\cdot ,t+h)-w(\cdot ,t)}{h}-\Delta w(\cdot ,t)\right\|_X=0.$$ So, this reference doesn't explain what I want. It just gave a new interpretation to problem with new names, through an abstract approach. Why is this new approach useful?

Comment: @UweStroinski In other words, I would like a motivation for this concept of solution. I would like to know why is reasonable to look for a solution in that sense. Since a partial differential equation arises from a physical phenomena, any concept of solution should be reasonable or should have a motivation.